# Finding elements by xpath pattern in Selenium python

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am working with selenium python and lettuce to test django application.

There are many elements having xpath in the following pattern and i don't know how many of these elements exists in the document.

```
.//*[@id='accordion-note-1']
.//*[@id='accordion-note-2']
.//*[@id='accordion-note-3']
.//*[@id='accordion-note-4']
```

Is there any way to use pattern in **driver.find_elements_by_xpath** ? 
Basically my purpose is to get all items having this pattern of xpath.

Comment: If xpath 1.0 - `.//*[starts-with(@id, 'accordion-note')]`

Comment: I don't know what version i am using ? @splash58 ..... How to find out ?

Comment: i dom't know about selenium too. If the answer below will return error, try my expression

Comment: @splash58 your answer worked very well. Below noor has edited his answer as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure this will work, but you can try by using the below xpath:

```
.//*[starts-with(@id, 'accordion-note')]
```

here is the link
http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_starts-with.html

u can also use contain here like

```
.//*[contains(@id, 'accordion-note')]
```

Comment: I have used your answer like this. **world.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[matches(@id, 'accordion - IT - \\d+')]")**. And this is the error i got this error. **The given selector .//*[matches(@id, 'accordion - IT - \d+')] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement**.

Comment: It didn't worked out. Gonna try the upper comment. Please upvote the question as well so some one else might answer it.

Comment: @AdilMalik have u succedded?

Comment: Yes. Thanks Guys. So the point is we can use patterns in xpath ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115952/discussion-between-noor-and-adil-malik).