# How to select the first N website elements matching one CSS selector in python selenium?

Tags: python, css, selenium, screen-scraping

I am screen scraping with phantomJS in a python/selenium setup.
Specifically, I need the first N elements that match one CSS selector.

The challenge is that there are more than double as much matching elements present within the website, so the call below takes too long (**speed is a major requirement for me**):

```
targets =  WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector)))
```

Is there any way to define a cutoff for found elements, like:

```
EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector[0:N])))
```

*My previous solution without CSS selectors was to copy all html in one call, convert it to text and then get the (text) elements of interest by text parsing, using a dict of words to keep/remove. This was more than 4x faster. However, this is not suitable/scalable since the dict needs to be maintained.*

**How to select the first n website elements matching one CSS selector in python selenium?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below solution to get required number of matched nodes:

```
n_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('css_selector')[:N])
```

Comment: many thanks - works like a charm. I also came across another solution using positions() to define a range within selectors - in case someone else is reading this for future references https://stackoverflow.com/a/48146404/6060083